# Bootstrap grid system not working - columns stack vertically

Tags: css, grid, bootstrap-4, system

I am trying to learn Bootstrap. Would like to create simple 3 columns in 1 row.

My code looks like this (just copied it from example in Bootstrap Documentation).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        One of three columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried with all kinds of sizes - "col-sm", "col-xs", etc, tried also "col", "col-different sizes", "col-different sizes-different numbers from 2 to 12" and the columns always stack vertically.
None of the solutions on stackoverflow and the internet seem to work either.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The markup is working as expected (https://www.codeply.com/go/uiBwHc8yYt), so most likely Bootstrap 4 CSS is not properly referenced in your HTML file.

Comment: I think you haven't included the CSS file correctly.

Comment: Try adding bootstarp css like this <link rel="stylesheet" href="stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/…; integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: I copied Bootstrap starting template from their docs again and it works now, indeed it was the lack of css inclusion. Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you guys for help.

The reason was not including Bootstrap's CSS properly.